# String Not Appended to Dynamically Created Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've researched this in depth on stackexchange and I don't think I am making a 'common' mistake, and the other answers have not solved this.

The problem is I am trying to append data to a DEFINITELY existing div of a certain ID. What I DO know is that the div is dynamically generated, and that is probably why it is hidden.

Despite using jquery `on` I cannot seem to get jquery to find the particular div.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function example_append_terms(data) {
        var sender_id = data['sender_id'];
        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            if (k != 'sender_id') {
                html = '<span data-lemma="' + v['key'] + '" class="lemma">' + v['name'] + '</span>';

                $('#' + sender_id + ' .lemmas').append(html);
            }
        });
    }

    function example_get_options(data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/example/',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(data))
                example_append_terms(data)
            },
            failure: function(data) {
                alert('Got an error dude');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }


    $(document).on('click', ".example-synset-option", function() {
        var synset = $(this).data('name');
        var sender_id = $(this).attr('id')
        example_get_options({
            'synset': synset,
            'sender_id': sender_id,
        });
    });

});
```

On clicking a certain div, an action is fired to "get options" which in turn runs an ajax function. The ajax function runs the "replacer" function `example_append_terms`.

Having tested up to `example_append_terms` the .each iteration is definitely working. But when I did tested `$('#' + sender_id + ' .lemmas').length` I continue to get 0.

Where is this jquery `newb` going wrong?

Comment: Where do you generate the element with `.example-sysnet-option` class?

Comment: @1Up can you show us the format of your **data**.?

Comment: Is `$('#' + sender_id + ' .lemmas')` already present on page. If yes, please show its HTML

Comment: The space before .lemmas is supposed to be there, right?

Comment: @KevinWheeler whether target the subclass `.lemmas` or simply target sender_id it does not work. Updating question.

Comment: See updated. For a fact the ID is present on the page after the previous functions are triggered.

Comment: nobody asked for more javascript, what was asked for was a) an example of your response from the ajax, and b) the HTML showing where (you think) the `$('#' + sender_id + ' .lemmas')` should be

Comment: Might be a silly question - but sender_id isn't a number/start with a number does it?

Comment: No it doesn't start with a number. Using firebug the ID is there (a div dynamically added) and its definitely not seeing what is clearly in the document.

Comment: by way of example, here is a targeted id: `cute-1-cunning.s.01` yet I am aware none of these characters are illegal

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing stuff...

For some inexplicable reason fetching the data attribute worked better than the id..

```
function intellitag_append_terms(data) {
    var sender_id = $('*[data-location="'+data['sender_id']+'"] .lemmas');        
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        if (k != 'sender_id') {
            html = $('<span data-lemma="' + v['key'] + '" class="label label-primary lemma">' + v['name'] + '</span>');
            html.appendTo(sender_id)
            //$('#' + sender_id).append(html);
        }
    });
}
```